# Animating a select number of characters in a UILabel

Tags: swift, uilabel, core-animation

Is there a way to achieve this effect in a UILabel?

https://codepen.io/TravisL12/pen/MaWmbo

```
    <h1>Loading
      <span class='dot' id="dot-1">.</span>
      <span class='dot' id="dot-2">.</span>
      <span class='dot' id="dot-3">.</span>
    </h1>
$delay: 1.5s;

body {
  background: lightblue;
}

.dot {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-animation: dot $delay alternate infinite;
  animation: dot $delay alternate infinite;
}

#dot-1 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.5s;
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
}

#dot-2 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1.5s;
  animation-delay: 1.5s;
}

#dot-3 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2.5s;
  animation-delay: 2.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes dot {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

I thought about animating the whole string, as if each state is a different string, but I believe I will end up fading in/out the whole string, not just the period.
Is it even possible with just one UILabel or do I need one UILabel for each period?

EDIT: This question isn’t a duplicate. My animation is more complex.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Objectivec c : How to animate "Loading..." text on uilabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24359730/objectivec-c-how-to-animate-loading-text-on-uilabel)

Comment: This isn’t a duplicate. The animation in trying to implement is more complex.